# Discord.js Invalid Form Body

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

At the time I am trying to learn how to make a discord bot and I got an error I dont know waht it means or how to fix it. I made a command for welcome messages with a youtube tutorial and now it stopped working.

Error:

```
DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
7.options[0].name[APPLICATION_COMMAND_INVALID_NAME]: Command name is invalid
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop\Manager\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:659:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop\Manager\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:458:14)
    at async REST.request (C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop\Manager\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:902:22)
    at async GuildApplicationCommandManager.set (C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop\Manager\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:173:18)
```

Code:

```
const {Message, Client, SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits} = require("discord.js");
const welcomeSchema = require("../../Models/Welcome");
const {model, Schema} = require("mongoose");

module.exports = {
    name:"setup-welcome",
    description:"Set up your welcome message for the discord bot.",
    UserPerms:["BanMembers"],
    category:"Moderation",
    options: [
        {
            name:"Channel",
            description:"Channel for welcome messages.",
            type:7,
            required:true
        },

        {
            name:"welcome-message",
            description:"Enter your welcome message.",
            type:3,
            reqired:true
        },

        {
            name:"welcome-role",
            description:"Enter your welcome role.",
            type:8,
            required:true
        }
    

    ],
                
    async execute(interaction) {
        const {channel, options} = interaction;

        const welcomeChannel = options.getChannel("channel");
        const welcomeMessage = options.getString("welcome-message");
        const roleId = options.getRole("welcome-role");

        if(!interaction.guild.members.me.permissions.has(PermissionFlagsBits.SendMessages)) {
            interaction.reply({content: "I don't have permissions for this.", ephemeral: true});
        }

        welcomeSchema.findOne({Guild: interaction.guild.id}, async (err, data) => {
            if(!data) {
                const newWelcome = await welcomeSchema.create({
                    Guild: interaction.guild.id,
                    Channel: welcomeChannel.id,
                    Msg: welcomeMessage,
                    Role: roleId.id
                });
            }
            interaction.reply({content: 'Succesfully created a welcome message', ephemeral: true});
        })
    }
}
```

I tried a few things like changing the construction of the bot or change some thing like the command options.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Channel` argument is invalid, since all names need to be lowercase only. Change it to `channel`, for example, and it will work.

Comment: I tryid but I didnt worked.
here is the full error:
https://justpaste.it/7tlci

Comment: @EagleWarrior the issue in this error is with another command, "setup-welcome". You're adding an optional argument before the next non-optional one, which isn't supported. Reorder the arguments so all required arguments come first, followed by all optional ones.

Comment: I thougt everything is required because I gave all options the required true tag abd dont need to do this on the command

Comment: @EagleWarrior I misread the original question, sorry about that. discord.js seems to interpret your command as if it was optional, can you show me where you register the commands?

Comment: You mean my Commands.js file?

Comment: Depends, I just want to see where you're telling discord.js what your commands are

Comment: I dont know if this is the right because I made parts of the bot a while ago but here is the commands.js:
https://justpaste.it/cu6by

Comment: @EagleWarrior I just saw it, you misspelled `required`. You spelt it `reqired` instead.

Comment: Where di you see it?

Comment: In the `welcome-message` option in your original question. The `required` param is spelled `reqired` instead, which will make any lookup to `required` automatically return false.

Comment: Its working now! Thanks for your help and your invested time